# Is there anyway that allows me to use System.IO in a UWP application

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm currently working on a UWP application and one of the things I need to do is write bytes to files using the `System.IO` class. This is because one of the libraries my application depends on uses the `System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes()` method.

Using the `StorageFolder` class isn't quite something that I'm looking to do since a couple of the projects I am making (some are not UWP, some are CLIs) depend on this library I have written and the `StorageFolder` is only available in UWP.

I've added `broadFileSystemAccess` as one of the capabilities of my UWP application. However, after reading the documentation carefully I found out that this capability only affects the `StorageFolder` class and not the `System.IO` class. In addition, I'm the only person who will be using this application, so I thought that enabling the file access rights in the System Settings (as shown in the image provided) would help. However that did not help at all

[image]

Here is the exception message that I am getting

`"Access to the path 'C:\\proj\\proj_tig\\Project 112\\bin\\x64\\Debug\\AppX\\Dependencies.zip' is denied."`

Is there any possible way to use the `System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes()` method at all in UWP?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anyway that allows me to use System.IO in a UWP application

For checking the path, and it looks a apps installation folder, unfortunately, the installation folder is read-only, we can't write data into. we suggest you use app' [local folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/fileio-learning-track) that with full permission, and you could use `System.IO` namespace to access. For more detail please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've been doing more and more research on UWP and I've ultimately decided against using it for this application I'm building due to sandboxing causing me more issues than solving.

Comment: UWP app run in the sandbox is by-design, and if you do want to make uwp app has more permissions, you could make desktop extension for uwp app, for more please research **UWP with Desktop Extension** . And if the answer is helpful please consider mark it.